# Query regarding resetting of cursor

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

We are binding a property of type double to a text box in Silverlight application, while running the application on changing the value in the text box , cursor moves to first place not allowing the user to enter the value.

For example : If user is trying to enter  99999.9 , after 99999 value when we are trying to enter "." , cursor goes to first position thereby not allowing user to enter 99999.9

This problem is occurring, when we add  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged in textbox binding property. When we remove this property then the textbox working in normal way.

Please help me to resovle this issue.

Thanks

XAML:

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtUtil" IsReadOnly="{Binding IsReadable,Mode=TwoWay}" Text="{Binding Utilization,Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnValidationError=True,ValidatesOnExceptions=True}" Width="70" Height="30"/>
```

C#

```
public double Utilization { 
  get { return utilization; } 
  set { utilization = value; 
        OnPropertyChanged("Utilization");
  }
}
```

Comment: Could this be fixed by using a `DependencyProperty` instead?

Comment: Is anything happening in your `OnPropertyChanged` method other than raising the `PropertyChanged` event? I was unable to reproduce the behavior you described using the provided code.

Comment: This was happening when we host the application in server and browsing the link from local.

Comment: Any progress on this? Where is your C# code located? In the `Page` or a `UserControl` or is it a separate class?

Comment: I did not find any solution yet. Iam following MVVM pattern.Hence c# code is located in viewmodel file (Seperate class).

Comment: Does the solution require that the `TextBox` restrict entry of any alphas or numbers outside the range, or is it an acceptable solution to have the validation error show for invalid values?

Answer (score 0):

Please use textchanged event and in that set selectionstart property to textlength

Comment: I have used txtUtil.SelectionStart = txtUtil.Text.Length. This is not resetting the cursor position. But this inducing other issue like... not allowing me to enter decimal point "." until i enter numbers of maxlength. For example if the maxlength of the textbox is 10 then till i enter all the 10 digits it is not allowing me enter decimal point

Comment: why are you using maxlength if your number has length greater than 10

Comment: We have a requirement that the control should accept only 10 digits and two decimal places